# Next element from stream in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

Is there a method or way to get each next element from a stream?

For example if there is a stream looking like

```
def natural: Stream[Long] = {
  def naturalHelper: Long => Stream[Long] = {
    n => n #:: naturalHelper(n+1)
  }
  naturalHelper(1)
}

val s = natural
```

I'm looking for something like `s.next()`, returning 2 on the first call, s.next() = 3 on the next call, and so on... without using `var`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make it an iterator

```
val s = natural.iterator
s.next()
s.next()
```

Comment: Right on.  And if that's the _only_ thing you plan on doing with the Stream, you probably shouldn't be using a Stream at all, since Streams save results and will eventually eat up all of your memory.

Comment: I agree with @AmigoNico any method with counter inside will do the job.